# Weird 500 internal server error

Tags: error, server-setup, http-error-500

I have a pretty weird error in a Magento setup:

The page loads normally and shows in the browser. However, when I inspect it using firebug, the server returns the page as a server error 500!

This leads to problems for Google which states that it cannot access the pages.

Again, the pages do show, you can browse the shop normally.

Some pages load without this 500 error (e.g. homepage), but many pages have this effect.

I already checked the file permissions, the memory limit (set this high to 1024M to be sure) and the .htaccess file and both seem to be fine. Any ideas of what could produce this?

The server error log does not shield any insights.

Comment: What errors are there in your logs (apache and/or system.log)?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no errors generated. The 500 error shows in the access.log of Apache, but there is no entry in the error.log. Magento does not show any errors in the system.log or exception.log

Comment: do they take ages to load? In which case you should higher your -idle_timeout

Answer (score 1):

Internal Server Errors and/or Gateway Errors can almost always tracked back to one or another PHP error. Turn on your logs and see what you can find from there.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced such issue before, it was due to permission. Please check permission of index.php in root folder. May be this helps you to resolve issue of 500 Internal Server.