# Please Please Help With Error 500 Internal Server Error after upgrading from 1.7 to 1.9

Tags: admin, error

My website and my entire eCommerce admin has crashed and just showing error 500 internal error

what can i do to recover my ecommence and my website

this is what am getting when i click my site http://www.zycaa.com/perfumestore

Now i have lost my brand new website and eCommerce

What can i do to recover or access my admin

the website was working with products on it

I was upgrading magento 1.7 to 1.9

It said the upgrade is complete just click refresh

when i clicked refresh to see the upgrade i got no response,everything just stopped responding.

i tried to go back to the admin thats when everything just shut and crashed

i received the ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

I can't see or know what error because i can't access the admin and the website is giving my the same error 500

http://www.zycaa.com/perfumestore/admin

Comment: Please provide more details. Did you install new plugins? whether your site working before ? What would be the probable cause to happen this.? Try to provide these details

Comment: What version? What do the web server error logs show? Error 500 means that the server itself is having issues. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7460/attempted-magento-backup-now-throws-500-internal-server-error-page , http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24507/weird-500-internal-server-error , http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1462/with-htaccess-file-server-gives-error-500-internal-server-error

Answer (score 5):

This is most likely due to your file permissions not set properly and this is also stated as the reason in your 500 error page.

You will firstly need to know if your server is running suPHP / suEXEC. If it is, make sure all files are set to 644 and all directories to 755.

Changing the permissions should usually be enough to resolve the issue.

You may need to take note though because if you run the Magento in-built backup feature, it may reset the file permission back to those which includes 666 and 777 which may cause the error again and you will have to reset it back to 644 and 755.

Comment: In all likelihood this is exactly the answer you need. I am attaching the following link which should help you set these permissions with SSH http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions